# how to extract properties from an object NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object

I'm having issues getting a property inside an object, using get request in NodeJs(with express). I Have the following object:

```
const amigos = [{
    id: 1,
    nombre: "laura",
    pais: "Inglaterra",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 0, lenguaje:"java"},"python","c++"],
    hobbies : ["leer" , "pescar" , "tenis"]
  },
{
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Rocío",
    pais: "Argentina",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 1, lenguaje:"C++"},"kotlin","GO"],
    hobbies : ["correr" , "Natacion" , "Equitación"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Fede",
    pais: "Argentina",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 2, lenguaje:"PHP"},"python","swift"],
    hobbies : ["Tiro con arco" , "Crossfit" , "Boxeo"]
},
{
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Dany",
    pais: "Colombia",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 3, lenguaje:"java"},"javascript","c++"],
    hobbies : ["Futbol" , "pescar" , "Trekking"]
},
{
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Mariano",
    pais: "Argentina",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 4, lenguaje:"javascript"},"python","java"],
    hobbies : ["Correr" , "Natacion" , "Basketball"]
}]

module.exports = amigos;
```

And I want to extract only the hobbies.

I have tried the following, but it keeps bringing me back the whole object. Not only the hobbies, which is what I need:

```
app.get("/amigos", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200);
    // const hobbiesParam = req.params.hobbies; 
//     const response = amigos.map(
//       (a) => { return a.hobbies.toLowerCase()
// });
    res.json(amigos.hobbies);
  });
```

**Edit:** The expected output should be an array of objects just with the name and hobbies per person:

```js
[
  { "nombre": "laura",
    "hobbies": [
      "leer",
      "pescar",
      "tenis"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
const amigos = [{
    id: 1,
    nombre: "laura",
    pais: "Inglaterra",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 0, lenguaje:"java"},"python","c++"],
    hobbies : ["leer" , "pescar" , "tenis"]
  },
{
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Rocío",
    pais: "Argentina",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 1, lenguaje:"C++"},"kotlin","GO"],
    hobbies : ["correr" , "Natacion" , "Equitación"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Fede",
    pais: "Argentina",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 2, lenguaje:"PHP"},"python","swift"],
    hobbies : ["Tiro con arco" , "Crossfit" , "Boxeo"]
},
{
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Dany",
    pais: "Colombia",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 3, lenguaje:"java"},"javascript","c++"],
    hobbies : ["Futbol" , "pescar" , "Trekking"]
},
{
    id: 4,
    nombre: "Mariano",
    pais: "Argentina",
    lenguajes :[ {id: 4, lenguaje:"javascript"},"python","java"],
    hobbies : ["Correr" , "Natacion" , "Basketball"]
}]

console.log( amigos.map( ({ nombre, hobbies }) => ({ nombre, hobbies }) ) );
```